# Blurry Image when exported to 32×32

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, favicon

I am trying to create a favicon for our website. I created something at 7000×7000 and then reduced the size to 32×32.
(I may be using the wrong terminology here. The website we use, says the maximal favicon size is 32×32.)

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Blurry Image when exported]

The issue is that it’s super blurry when a shortcut is created in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the approach you should take.

You can not reduce a logo to a 16x16px size for a favicon and expect to work. Your logo can not even be read.

In this specific case, take your logo, crop square leaving only the red swash on gray background... That could work as a favicon.